# Creating multiple children of a process and maintaining a shared array of all their PIDs

Tags: c, ipc

I have forked a couple of times and have created a bunch of child processes in C. I want to store all their PIDs in a shared array. The ordering of the PIDs does not matter. For instance, I created 32 processes. I would like to have a 32 integer long array that would store each of their PIDs and is accessible to each of these processes. What could be the best way to do this.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147760/how-to-get-child-pid-in-c you should be able to store that value in any array of choice.

Comment: Did you fork with the fork(2) call? If so the child process will have a new address space and so there is no shared memory. If you really want to do this, you have to create a shared memory mapping in some other way e.g. with mmap() on a file descriptor you open before fork()'ing for the first time. You can then store the return value of each fork() in that area (it will return the child process PID in the parent thread, and 0 in the child thread). You should probably explore using pthreads instead of forks, if you need shared memory, it is also less resource intensive, and has mutexes etc.

Comment: you need to use `mmap`. but still it's better for the subprocesses to know which index they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a program that illustrates what you want using mmap():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PIDS 32

volatile pid_t *pids;

// Called for each child process
void do_child(void)
{
  int c;
  printf("Child: %d - pid array: ", getpid());

  for (c=0; c<10; c++) {
    printf("%d%s", pids[c], c==9?"\n":" ");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int c;
  pid_t pid;

  // Map space for shared array
  pids = mmap(0, MAX_PIDS*sizeof(pid_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
              MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  if (!pids) {
    perror("mmap failed");
    exit(1);
  }
  memset((void *)pids, 0, MAX_PIDS*sizeof(pid_t));

  // Fork children
  for (c=0; c<10; c++) {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
      // Child process
      do_child();
      exit(0);
    } else if (pid < 0) {
      perror("fork failed");
    } else {
      // Store in global array for children to see
      pids[c] = pid;
      sleep(1);
    }
  }
  exit(0);
}
```