# Creating a shared string array which children processes can access

Tags: c, arrays, string, fork

I am declaring an array of string using

```
char users[10][256];
```

then I am forking and creating 10 child processes.
I need each child process to access and modify this string array. How do I do that ?

Comment: What did you do so far, in addition to defind a matrix of chars....

Comment: Same for `int`s  but "strings"s here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26161486/694576 I'd consider this current question a duplicate to the one linked.

Comment: I’d agree that it is a duplicate, but the linked question does not consider MS Windows, which Mark Segals’s answer does. Or does MSW support `mmap`?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use Shared Memory.

Under Linux, you can check [this](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) out. It uses `shmget`, `shmat` and `shmdt` to create shared memory segments, get shared memory segments and detach shared memory segments respectfully.

Under Windows, you can check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx) out. It uses `OpenFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` to create "File Mappings" and map them to the process's virtual memory respectfully.

Both, finally, achieve the same result.